# Effective way to interpret data from Excel Export

Tags: excel, export

My business works with a partner business. The partner business has a database we can access using web forms. We have to do hourly/daily metric reports which involves exporting the data & copy/pasting into a google sheet which then gets us our numbers.

My question is, is there a more efficient way of grabbing this data if backend access to the database has been rejected. Ideally I'd like to do my own queries but since I have no access I run the query on the webpage, export to excel, then copy paste the data into a google sheet and then use the query function to get what I need. What would be the solutions you would advise? Should I ask for a web service? Any way to automate exports? Any ideas?

Comment: Is this actually a question about `.SLN` (solution) files, or is that an incorrect tag?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is very general and vague, and you won't be able to get an answer without providing a lot more information.  For example, what kind of database is this data stored in?  Why can't you get access if it's a "partner"? Are you sure they don't have an API for data access?  What does `backend access to the database has been rejected` mean?  You question sounds like something you need to ask the "partner" (as opposed to strangers who have zero knowledge of your data or the situation). See the [tour] as well as "[help/on-topic]".

Comment: Removed .sln tag. Thanks for your response. I'll make sure to ask if they have an API for data access

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing appears to be web-scraping.  If so, you can scrape HTML tables from a website from within a Google sheet.  Absolutely no backend access using the IMPORTHTML function.

**See this excellent video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95c0OlsjKgU**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this method before posting & I keep getting an error fetching url. I believe it may be because the website is only accessible locally on the intranet

Comment: Do you know the internal ip address?  OR can you find out what it is?  You can use the ip address directly in your call.

Comment: I had no idea about this. This actually helps me with some other stuff I was working on and possibly this. Thanks for the tip!